# Disable quick view in product list Prestashop1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

what is the correct way to disable quick view in product in prestashop 1.6

```
{if isset($quick_view) && $quick_view}
 <a class="quick-view" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"      rel="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Quick view'}">
<span>{l s='Quick view'}</span>
</a>
{/if}
```

isset($quick_view) where is this set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is in PrestaShop back-office -> `Modules` -> `Modules` -> `Theme configurator` -> `Display quick view window on homepage and category pages`

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop 1.7.x, you have to go to the theme : `/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl` and remove the code quickview